# Why is the forward DNS needed to verify crawlers

Tags: dns, web-crawler, search-engine

From google's support site -

> To verify Googlebot as the caller:
>
> Run a reverse DNS lookup on the accessing IP address from your logs,
>   using the host command. Verify that the domain name is in either
>   googlebot.com or google.com Run a forward DNS lookup on the domain
>   name retrieved in step 1 using the host command on the retrieved
>   domain name. Verify that it is the same as the original accessing IP
>   address from your logs.

My question is why is the forward DNS lookup necessary? Can an attacker create a DNS record of the form `crawl-xx-xx-xx-xx.googlebot.com`?

I am actually seeing this in my logs - from other crawlers as well. Ip's that if I reverse DNS lookup come from the correct domain, but the forward lookup does not return the IP. Wondering how is this possible..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse zones can be served by anybody. If you own the IP space, and get your isp to forward reverse lookups, you can serve a reverse zone that points at anything you want.

As an attacker I can buy any IP block and serve my zone `4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa` that says all records are in `crawl-xx-xx-xx-xx.googlebot.com`

I cannot control google's forward dns for that zone though. So even though I can get a reverse lookup for `1.2.3.4` to return `crawl-12-34-56-78.googlebot.com`, I cannot get a forward lookup on `crawl-12-34-56-78.googlebot.com` to return `1.2.3.4`.

The inconsistent entries in your logs are almost certainly third-party bots trying (quite well) to impersonate google.

Comment: Thank you that's very clear. I see a ton of Baidu spider UA's present this exact behavior as well. I wonder if all major search engine crawlers adhere to this practice?